# Converting (fractional) degrees to minutes and seconds

Tags: trigonometry, fractions

I need a refresher on degrees/minutes/seconds
When we have
$a:= \frac{7^\circ}{48}$=7(1' 15'')

This is because we have $a:= \frac{7^\circ}{48} = 7\frac{1}{48} = 7 \frac{75}{3600} =  7 \frac{60}{3600} + \frac{15}{3600} = 7 \frac{1}{60} + \frac{15}{3600} = 7(1' 15'')$

But how dow we get
 `7(1' 15'') = 8' 45''`?

Comment: Do you mean to divide $7^\circ$ by $48$ and already know that $\frac 1{48}^\circ = 1'\,15''$? -- Note that $7\cdot 15''=105''=60''+45''=1'\,45''$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:The process to get `7(1′15″)` from  7°÷48 I figured as I described in the post. I am confused on how I can get 8'45'' from the 7(1'15'')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a computation in basis $60$:
$$7\cdot(1'\, 15'')=7(1'+15'')=7'+7\cdot 15''=7'+105''$$
Now $105 >60$ so we subtract $60$ from $105$ and carry $1$ to the minutes, i.e.
$$7'+105''=7'+(1'+45')=(7'+1')+45''=8' \,45''.$$

*Answer for the real question* (which I misread):
\begin{align}7°\div 48&=(7\cdot 60)'\div 48=420'\div 48= 8'+(36'\div 48)= 8'+(3'\div 4)\\&=8'+(3\cdot 60)''\div 4= 8'\;45''.
\end{align}

Comment: I thought $7^\circ⋅(1′15″) = 7 + 1/60 + 15/3600$. We multiply not add?

Comment: Sure. I misread and thought of a multiplication by $7$. I'll add the answer to the real question (leaving this one, as it might be useful).

Comment: I didn't understand this equality \begin{align}7°\div 48&=(7\cdot 60)'\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add $\div 48$. I've fixed it. Is it clear now?

Comment: I don't understand this equation `420′÷48=8′+(36′÷48)`. Seems it is exactly the same thing as my question. How did the `420'` break to `8' +..`?

Comment: $8$ is the quotient and $36$ is the remainder when you perform the ordinary division of $420$ by $48$. The only thing I add is that when the dividend is smaller than the divisor, I multiply the dividend by $60$ (when you calculate in base $10$, you bring a $0$, i.e. you multiply the remainder by $10$ to have the first decimal place).

Comment: Isn't `8'` equal to `8*(1/60)`? So isn't $420′÷48=420*($\frac{1}{60}*\frac{1}{48}$? I am sorry, I am pretty sure what you say is accurate, I am somehow confused following you :(

Comment: I suppose you mean $8°(1/60)$? This would mean expressing $8'$ in degrees. But $8'$ is less than a degree.

Comment: My understanding is that eg  4° 2' 3'' means 4 + \frac{2}{60}$ + \frac{3}{60*60}$. Hence I said that 8' equal to 8*(1/60)

Comment: That is true, but what's this conversion good for?

Comment: If that conversion I mentioned is correct they why isn't 420' replaced with 420*(1/60) in your equation. I think I am lost. Could you please elaborate on how we get each part of the equation step by step. I think I am misunderstanding something hence I can't get your answer fully (and I suspect my post should have the same core confusion). Sorry for taking much time from you

Comment: What would be the point to divide by 60? We would obtain the value in degrees that we started from. I recall we had to convert in degrees because we want ti divide the value in degrees ($7$) by $48$ and this value is less than $48$. Think of waht you do when you have to divide in base $10$ $7$ by $48$: as it is smaller then $48$, you convert it in tenths: this makes 70 tenths, and now $70>48$, so we can divide (with a remainder).

Comment: The point of converting is that is the definition. 1'=1/60 hence 420'=420/60. By not dividing it you seem to treat 420' as 420 and that is the part that is confusing me

Comment: $1'=1/60\color{red}{°}$. You have units on both sides. Afterwards, I don't mind about units: I know that mathematically, I have to make calculations in base $60$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by converting everything to seconds.
$$1' 15'' = 1 \times 60 + 15 = 75 \text { seconds}$$
Then do the multiplication.
$$7 \times 75 = 525 \text{ seconds}$$
Then divide by $60$ and keep the remainder in order to convert seconds to minutes and seconds.
$$\frac{525}{60} = 8 \text{ with remainder } 45$$
so
$$7 \; (1' 15'') = 8' 45''$$
The only tricky part may be doing the division with remainder. Some calculators and programming languages have special functions for this task. But if you are using a simple four-function calculator, you can first divide $525$ by $60$ with result $8.75$.  You then know the integer part of the division is $8$. To find the remainder, one way is to compute $525 - 8 \times 60 = 45$.  Alternatively, $0.75 \times 60 = 45$ will also work to find the remainder.

Comment: You get the correct result but I think they way you did it not the proper. Because 15'' := $/frac{15}{60*60}$ and you seem to do the calculation based on hourly minutes and seconds for `1' 15''`

Comment: @Jim Amazing that I got the right answer, then! No, seriously, all that is required for this problem is the knowledge that there are 60 seconds in one minute of arc. If the problem involved degrees as well, we would also need the fact that there are 60 minutes in one degree, but we don't need to know that for the present problem.